# How to Aggregate data from a set within a document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document that's modeled like this:

```
{ 
  _id: '1', 
  timeEntries: [
    { _id: '1',
      hours: '1'
    },
    { _id: '2',
      hours: '2'
    },
  ],
  totalHours: 3
}
```

Right now, every time I add a timeEntry to the set of timeEntries in my document, I also increment the totalHours property by the hours in the added timeEntry.

Instead of incrementing every time I $addToSet, I want to be able to call a method on the model of my document (virtual field?) to get the total hours from the document's timeEntries.

How would I go about doing this?

**Update**

Additionally, my timeEntries are actually stored as an array of reference.

Example:

```
[ 5bcf5e53e452b800134787dd, 5bcf5f42e452b800134787de ]
```

And I need a way to populate the hours property inside of the virtual field

Schema:

```
const companyHourLogSchema = new Schema({
  dateOpened: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now,
 },
  dateClosed: {
  type: Date,
 },
  _id: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  auto: true,
 },
  company: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Company',
 },
  timeEntries: [{
  type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'TimeEntry',
}],
  title: {
  type: String,
  default: 'Current',
},
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***update***

because the time entries are saved as references you need to use mongoose [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to get the entries first

```
Model.find(/*your condition here*/).populate('timeEntries');
```

to get the timeEntries populated with the log.

---

you can use [virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals)  as follows:

```
schema.virtual('totalHours').get(function () {
     return this.timeEntries.reduce((agg,tiE) => agg + tiE.hours ,0);
});
```

then you can use it as follows:

```
  console.log(modelInstance.totalHours);
```

Comment: My timeEntries are actually references, and the reduce would be trying to operate on [ 5bcf5e53e452b800134787dd, 5bcf5f42e452b800134787de ] etc... How could I nested objects inside of a virtual?

Comment: I need to see the mongoose schema, please update the question to add the mongoose schema

Comment: Updated the question.